# version of updated package

Tags: upgrade, apt, package-management

I'm running `apt-get upgrade` and see list of available packages which could be upgraded. Some of them without any version, how can I figure out what package version `apt` want to install here?

For example I see the next picture:

```
 base-files .. redmine redmine-mysql redmine-sqlite ...
```

How to know what to what version redmine will be upgraded ? And from what repository `apt` going to take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the versions of a package you could use:

```
apt-cache show redmine | grep -i version
```

Output is:

```
Version: 1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1
```

To see the versions and the repository you could use:

```
apt-cache policy redmine
```

Output is:

```
redmine:
  Installiert: (keine)
  Kandidat:    1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
     1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

**See:** [WebUpd8 - How To Find Out To Which PPA Repository A Package Belongs To](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/how-to-find-out-to-which-ppa-repository.html)

Comment: `# apt-cache policy redmine
redmine:
  Installed: 2.2.2+dfsg1-1~precise+1
  Candidate: 2.2.3+dfsg1-1~precise+1
  Version table:
     2.2.3+dfsg1-1~precise+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/redmine/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.2.2+dfsg1-1~precise+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages`

What stars means ? and numbers like 500 and 100 what they means ?

Comment: [The priority of each version/location is the number at the left of it. In this case, `500` and `100`.](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) If I understand [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Example_.231:_Pinning_the_ubuntu-x-swat.2BAC8-q-lts-backport-precise_PPA) correct, the `***` marks the package as "Candidate for upgrading".

Answer (score 0):

You can use aptitude for this instead of apt.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude show redmine
```