# How can I tell what version I have of 19.10 release?

Tags: software-installation, 19.10

I prefer to install mariadb without using the apt installation process. I'm not a fan of snap.
downloads.mariadb.org

The above site is asking for a version number for release 19.10 that I have installed. How can I tell?
I've tried a couple of methods but none show the kind of number (e.g. 19.10.04) they are looking for. Methods I've tried (e.g. cat /etc/issue) show ONLY 19.10 with no version.

MENU OS -> Release -> Version

Select Ubuntu and 19.10 Release. The version numbers suggested are
10.5 [Beta]
10.4 [Stable]
10.3 [Old Stable]

Comment: Isn't it asking you what *version of mariadb* you want to install?

Comment: It does NOT matter what Ubuntu you have. Mariadb is SERVER software and ALL Ubuntu are identical from the LTS up to the next LTS as soon as the point release is active. This question is about the version of MariaDB. Unrelated to Ubuntu. "The version numbers suggested are 10.5 [Beta] 10.4 [Stable] 10.3 [Old Stable]"  see the description between [] and decide yourself if you want the beta or a stable version.

Comment: Yep. I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [version of updated package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257641/version-of-updated-package)